# Hash Function to Generate 16 Alphanumerical Characters from Input String in C#

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

I need a function that will receive an input string, regardless its length and will output a fix length of 16 characters of 0-9A-Z. The function should has same output if input by the same string.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Note that such a short hash can't prevent deliberate collisions. Cost should be around 2^42 hash invocations, which is quite feasible. Accidental collisions should be rare, as long as you have less than a billion or so hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
public static string HashString(string text)
{
    const string chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);

    char[] hash2 = new char[16];

    // Note that here we are wasting bits of hash! 
    // But it isn't really important, because hash.Length == 32
    for (int i = 0; i < hash2.Length; i++)
    {
        hash2[i] = chars[hash[i] % chars.Length];
    }

    return new string(hash2);
}
```

`SHA256Managed` will generate an hash of 32 bytes. Then using the `%` (modulus) operator, we select a char for each byte. Note that we are wasting many bits in this way, but it isn't really important, because we have many more bits than we need (we need `log2(36) * 16 == 82.7`, we have 256 bits of hash)

Comment: Excellent..! It works great.. I thought before also that using modulus can help to fill the string to only accept desired char. Thank's @xanatos

Comment: Note that this approach introduces a bias in the output. The first couple of digits will be more common than the other characters. Fortunately this shouldn't lead to practical weaknesses for most use cases.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I was asking why... But then I realized... 256 / 36 = 7 with a remainder of 4... Those 4 :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a hash you should look into hash algorythms. One mostly known is **MD5** but that is a *128bits* hash algorythm. That means if you convert the raw bytes to a hex string it will be 32chars long (as most of the people know) so that means you need a hash function that is *64bits*. I did a quick search and came across **SipHash** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) and then I found a C# implementation (https://github.com/BrandonHaynes/siphash-csharp)

If you use the **SipHash** algorythm you should get a 16char length string.

Comment: 1) he problem with hex is that it doesn't use the full 36 characters the OP allows. This reduces the hash to 64 bit, instead of the 82 possible otherwise. 2) SipHash doesn't even try to be collision resistant when used without a key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses the MD5Hash algorithm.

```
public string GenerateHash(string str)
{
    using (var md5Hasher = MD5.Create())
    {
        var data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
        return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 16);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the answer from @Xanatos and decided to implement it.
That's when I realised I was creating an instance of a common problem I see.

When I enter keys for installing Windows, I sometimes get the digits wrong.  Especially when the barcode I am reading is scratched or faded.  It's simply the combination of similar characters, bad eyesight and wear on the barcode.

The following is plagiarised from @Xanatos' answer as an extension method, but removes similar characters (e.g. '1', 'I', 'O', '0' etc).

```
public static string ConstantLengthHash(this string Input)
{
    const string chars = "234679ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXYZ";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);

    SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);

    char[] hash2 = new char[16];

    // Note that here we are wasting bits of hash! 
    // But it isn't really important, because hash.Length == 32
    for (int i = 0; i < hash2.Length; i++)
    {
        hash2[i] = chars[hash[i] % chars.Length];
    }

    return new string(hash2);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use LINQ:

```
var c = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var rn = new Random();
var res = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(c, 16)
              .Select(x => x[rn.Next(x.Length)])
              .ToArray());
```

Also refer: [RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Implements a cryptographic Random Number Generator (RNG) using the
>   implementation provided by the cryptographic service provider (CSP).
>   This class cannot be inherited.

Or you can try this:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
Guid hashed = new Guid(md5.ComputeHash(g.ToByteArray()));
```

Comment: OP wants a hash not random strings.

Comment: @RahulTripathi It seems it creates a random hash string. I need the output is a fix length string, created base on a non-fix length input string. So the output string should not just a random. It should always has same output if the input is same. It is like to hash a password, but the output should limited to 16 char and only accept 0-9 and A-Z.

Comment: @BennyChen:- You can fix the length like this: `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 16);`